# How to edit the source code in module after installed it using zef?

Tags: web, microservices, raku, cro, zef

For example, I've installed the [Cro](http://cro.services) module, when I run my simple code:

```
 my %headers = {Authorization => OAuth realm="", oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_nonce="29515362", oauth_signature="KojMlteEAHlYjMcLc6LFiOwRnJ8%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1525913154", oauth_token="xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_version="1.0", User-Agent => Cro};

 my $resp = await Cro::HTTP::Client.get: 'http://api.fanfou.com/statuses/home_timeline.json',
     headers => [
            user-agent   => 'Cro',
            content-type => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            |%headers
     ];

 say $resp.header('content-type'); # Output: application/json; charset=utf-8;
 my Str $text = await $resp.body-text();
```

And it says 'Could not parse media type `application/json; charset=utf-8;`

```
Died with the exception:
    Could not parse media type 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'
      in method parse at /Users/ohmycloud/.perl6/sources/5B710DB8DF7799BC8B40647E4F9945BCB8745B69 (Cro::MediaType) line 74
      in method content-type at /Users/ohmycloud/.perl6/sources/427E29691A1F7367C23E3F4FE63E7BDB1C5D7F63 (Cro::HTTP::Message) line 74
      in method body-text-encoding at /Users/ohmycloud/.perl6/sources/427E29691A1F7367C23E3F4FE63E7BDB1C5D7F63 (Cro::HTTP::Message) line 83
      in block  at /Users/ohmycloud/.perl6/sources/F870148C579AB45DEB39F02722B617776C3D6D5F (Cro::MessageWithBody) line 49
```

It seems that `application/json; charset=utf8;` is not a valid `content-type`, so I add a test:

```
use Cro::MediaType;
use Test;

sub parses($media-type, $desc, &checks) {
    my $parsed;
    lives-ok { $parsed = Cro::MediaType.parse($media-type) }, $desc;
    checks($parsed) if $parsed;
}

parses 'application/json; charset=utf-8;', 'application/json media type with charset', {
    is .type, 'application', 'Correct type';
    is .subtype, 'json', 'Correct subtype';
    is .subtype-name, 'json', 'Correct subtype name';
    is .tree, '', 'No tree';
    is .suffix, '', 'No suffix';
    is .Str, 'application/json; charset=utf-8;', 'Stringifies correctly';
};

done-testing;
```

And the output is:

```
not ok 1 - application/json media type with charset
# Failed test 'application/json media type with charset'
# at cro_media.pl6 line 6
# Could not parse media type 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'
1..1
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1
```

the source code seems locate in the `/Users/ohmycloud/.perl6/sources/5B710DB8DF7799BC8B40647E4F9945BCB8745B69` file, and I add `';'?` after the `TOP` token:

```
token TOP { <media-type> ';'? }
```

save, and run my code again, but the error is the same. So how to make the change work? In Perl 5, I can just edit my `.pm` module, but in Perl 6, I dont't know what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this answer in zef's issues](https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/241#issuecomment-383823558), they state that "installations are immutable". 
It's probably a better option if you download Cro from its source, patch it and install again so that your application picks up the new version.

It might also happen that 'application/json' does not admit that charset declaration, or that there should be no space behind the ;. But the main issue here is that you shouldn't edit modules once installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll have a try.  There should have space behind the ; eg:  `text/plain; charset=UTF-8` , but the semicolon should't in the end, eg: `text/plain; charset=UTF-8;`

Answer (score 3):

As jjmerelo mentioned, **installations are immutable**, one solution is to download source code(include META6.json file), edit the code you want, then:

```
zef install . --/test
```

For simple test, it's ok for me.

As for `application/json; chartset=utf-8;` can't parse, I add a `;` in `MediaType.pm6`'s **`token`** token, make it possible to include `;` (maybe it's a bug, I don't know):

```
token token { <[A..Za..z0..9;!#$%&'*+^_`{|}~-]>+ }
```

installed locally, and it parse ok now.

Comment: this will impact other module and lead decode error, see  [github comment](https://github.com/croservices/cro-core/commit/a82bbcb01a781ca84acbc316d414dbf8074b29da)