# How can I rebuild an edited Raku module that I've downloaded?

Tags: build, module, raku, zef

I've installed Time::Duration and it failed most of its tests. I want to be able to rebuild the module - with my edits - from the locally stored module.

I edited the file that contains the module (that corresponds to Duration.pm6):

```
~/.perl6/sources/D00C101A0157E3EAC494310C9961F299240423E7
```

And then try building via it's json file:

```
zef --debug build ~/.perl6/dist/83839D8D315EEDEDFEAF211EE42E8D936ACE29CB
```

This returns:

```
===> # SKIP: No need to build Time::Duration:ver<2.00>
!!!> Build failure: ~/.perl6/dist/83839D8D315EEDEDFEAF211EE42E8D936ACE29CB at ~/.perl6/dist
```

I was hoping that this would rebuild the module with the change I made to the source.

Have I done this wrong, or am I going about this entirely wrong?

Comment: See also [How to edit the source code in module after installed it using zef?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50264214/2173773)

Comment: Installed modules are assumed to be immutable for the given version/auth/api.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it has been noted already you should not modify installed files. However, the workflow for testing changes of some module is pretty straight forward.

First:

```
# Fetch and extract the distribution, then change into its directory.
# If the distribution is still in zef's local file cache then it will
# skip the fetch and extraction steps.

zef look Time::Duration
```

Then:

At this point you can edit any of the files you wish.

Finally:

```
# test your changes without reinstalling (assumes all dependencies are installed)
zef test .

# Reinstall the modified version of Time::Duration using one of the following:
zef install . --force-install
zef uninstall Time::Duration && zef install .
```

Comment: Then submit a Pull Request with your changes to the main repo? ;)

Comment: @Scimon that does not fit into this workflow because what is fetched is not necessarily a git repo. Additionally the extract phase for a git repository does a `git checkout` from a temp directory into the zef store cache, which does not setup the e.g. `.git/` directory (nor do we really want `.git/` folders in the zef store cache). `zef browse zef bugtracker` and `zef browse zef source` sort of help, but only if the target distribution has the appropriate meta fields filled out (`Time::Duration` does not).

Comment: Please note that you don't need to do --force-install if you change the version in META6.json.

Answer (score 6):

You should `git clone` the code or download the zip package, edit the code you want, then `zef install .` if the current directory have a *META6.json* file.

Comment: Ok, and then use zef --force-install install . to update changes after you've done that once?

Comment: Yes.  The files in the $*REPO are considered to be immutable, so any changes you make to the source will remain undetected.